# Dixon's Q-test for outliers

Tags: python

I have Googled and can't find a built-in Dixon's Q-test for python.  I know that R has one, but my problem is that I have up to 9 locations, each having an instrument taking readings, reporting a value (we'll call it fluff) for one instance of time.  For reasons that we won't go into, the data is stored as fluff=-999 if there is something terribly wrong with the instrument.  Also, if the wind blows wrong, etc, the instrument can receive a crazy reading.  What I would like to do is called a Dixon's Qtest on the data to see if the reading at a location should be thrown out and not used to calculate other statistics on the data.  Maybe this will help...

`Data[location][time]` is a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
for t in Time:    
    L = []
    for loc in Location:
        L.append(Data[loc][t])

    #perform Dixon's Outlier test
    average = sum(L) / len(L)
    AverData[t] = average

    #more analysis
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The point of a Dixon's Q Test is to identify outliers by their deviation from a normal distribution, but in this case you know fluff (and possibly every other piece of data in the row/reading) is an outlier if fluff=-999.  So it sounds like a Dixon's Q is unnecessary for you.

Nonetheless, there is a raw implementation of a Dixon's Q test in Python [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_dixon_test.html#implementing-a-dixon-q-test-function).